# How do i refer to an object inside a method that it has invoked?

Tags: java

I've created a class named Rational which stores two private ints (numer and denom). I am trying to create a method that returns a new Rational object that contains the reciprocal of the object that invokes the method.

```
class Rational{

private int numer;
private int denom;

//sets numerator and denominator
public Rational (int numer, int denom){
    this.numer = numer;
    this.denom = denom;     
}

//copy constructor for a Rational object
public Rational (Rational copy){
    this(copy.getNumer(), copy.getDenom());
}

//sets numerator to parameter
public void setNumer(int numer){
    this.numer = numer;
}

//returns the stored numerator
public int getNumer(){
    return this.numer;
}

//sets denominator to parameter
public void setDenom(int denom){
    this.denom = denom;
}

//returns the stored denominator
public int getDenom(){
    return this.denom;
}

//returns a new Rational object that contains the reciprocal of the object that
//invoked the method
//Method #1
public Rational reciprocal(){
    this(rat1.getDenom(), rat1.getNumer()); 
}

//Method #2
public Rational reciprocal(Rational dup){
    this(dup.getDenom(), dup.getNumer());   
}
```

I want to invoke the reciprocal method with object rat1, but I can't figure out how to reference rat1's variables inside of the method. Is there any way to do this in a similar style to Method #1. (btw I'm aware that this does not work) Also, when using Method #2, why do I keep getting a "constructor call must be the first statement" error even though it is the first line?

Comment: Use: `return new Retional(getDenom(), getNumer());` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what `rat1` is meant to *be* in your `reciprocal` method... but the reason you can't just use `this(...)` is that these are methods, not constructors. It looks to me like you probably want:

```
public Rational reciprocal() {
    return new Rational(denom, numer);
}
```

If you want to call the methods instead, you could either just do them implicitly on `this`:

```
public Rational reciprocal() {
    return new Rational(getDenom(), getNumer());
}
```

Or you could use `this` explicitly:

```
public Rational reciprocal() {
    return new Rational(this.getDenom(), this.getNumer());
}
```

... but there's no point in your second `reciprocal` method because you could just call `x.reciprocal()` instead of `irrelevantRational.reciprocal(x)`.

As a side note, I'd rename both the methods and variables to avoid abbreviation:

```
private int numerator, denominator;

public int getNumerator() {
    return numerator;
}

// etc
```

I'd also make the class `final` and immutable, if I were you.